# Win32: How to get child process output buffer?

Tags: c++, winapi, redirect, console-application

I am testing on console standard I/O redirection using CreateProcess(x) function, and redirect the child process output to an anonymous pipe. Somehow, when I read from pipe output, I found that only characters are being redirect to the pipe, not the CHARINFO structure written to output handle using WriteConsoleOutput(x) function.

I would like to know if there is any way to redirect the CHARINFO structure so I can display it to my target output correctly.

These are the steps of what I've done so far:

1. On console application start, create new console buffer and set it as active console buffer.
2. Change new console buffer size and console window size to maximum allow.
3. Create anonymous pipe and some more steps to initialize the pipe, base on the [example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190351) shows in MSDN, also referencing [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5531/Redirecting-an-arbitrary-Console-s-Input-Output) article.
4. Spawn a child process using STARTINFO structure and redirect the I/O/E to the newly created pipe.
5. Start new thread to listen child process output.
6. Write the output onto active screen buffer, limiting to a small region, say, lower half of the screen buffer.

Step 6 is where I found the problem. At first I though I would get CHARINFO structure, so I try to cast the lpBuffer return by ReadFile(x) function to array of CHARINFO struc. Immediately I see the error. When I examine lpBuffer, I found that only characters stored in lpBuffer, not the Attributes.

Is there a way to redirect the CHARINFO in this case? If yes, how could I identified ReadFile(x) return buffer is array of CHARINFO or array of character? Need to differentiate because I cannot control how the child process output to console.

Comment: Maybe posting some code will help get some responses...

Comment: Actually I think I found solution, but just half there, now trying to figure out how to create a security descriptor for [Everyone].

Comment: an [Everyone] security descriptor is a NULL security descriptor